# How to use the x-axis to order the function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am using ggplot2 to create a scatter graph. For some reason it keeps using the y-axis variables to order my scatter graph. I'm new to this so I barely know what I'm doing, so if someoen could help, would be much appreciated!

What I've noticed is that my Rstudio orders the numbers going in order like 1,10,11,12...2,21,22,23 instead of going the standard 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

```
Diesel_Prices_Jan19 <- ggplot(Prices_4, aes(V4, V1))
Diesel_Prices_Jan19 + geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a tip its probably best to give a good reprex. Check the type of that column and maybe try turning it into a factor